# Limit scope of Network Adapters?

Tags: networking

Is it possible for me to limit the scope of my network adapters?
The situation is this:

I have an active LAN connection, AND I'm tethering my phone. 
Both have internet access, but only the LAN connection allows me to connect to my development server.

However, the LAN connection's internet access is severely restricted, and flaky, and I need to utilize my phone's tethering to get stable internet access.

Is there a way I can limit th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called [**routing**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_table). Tell your computer to only route packets bound for the LAN to the LAN adapter, and make the tethered device your [**default gateway**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_gateway).

Comment: D'you mind explaining how I can go about doing this?

Comment: "How do I modify my routing table?" should be a separate question. One where you also mention your OS.